# Popup html to be opened outside the iframe tag on fullscreen

Tags: html

I have used "header.html" in an iframe inside of "index.html" so "header.html" is shown on "index.html".

And I have added a popup link onto "header.html" and would like the popup to open outside of its iframe.

So when someone clicks on the button then another html page should be opened outside the iframe tag as an popup.

index.html code:

```html
<iframe src="header.html" width="100%"></iframe>
```

header.html code:

```
<a href="popup.html">POPUP</a>
<!-- When someone clicks on POPUP then popup.html should be opened as on popup on index.html -->
```

Comment: I don't think we can because of security reasons, because some would say that fiddling with iframes and non-iframes is quite risky - however I suppose we can use Javascript's `alert()` function though.

Comment: isn't there any alternative for this??

Comment: yeh! sure......

Comment: I think the easiest method is the [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) function in Javascript, but that can't be styled. Alternatively, I suppose you could link to another page which contains the popup content.

Comment: yeh! i also think the same....

Comment: is it  posibble that i use dropdown and the dropdown content can be outside iframe tag.... as it also hide beside iframe.. and i cannot increase the height of iframe...

Comment: I'm not sure, but another solution which would fix both of these would be to make the header as tall as the screen size and let it overflow over the content. However the issue with this is that the rest of the page becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Yes! It would be more good to make another page... By the way thank you bro, For the help...

Comment: I would also reccomend taking a look at PHP `include` and `require` as these can help make the same effect

Comment: i am new in programming and don't know much about php... You can say i am zero in PHP..... I am just trying with html css and java right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224580/discussion-between-corn-on-the-cob-and-harshit-mishra).

Comment: Do you want the contents of popup.html to show up in the index.html as maybe an alert or you want it to replace the content of the index.html file

Comment: no.. i dont want to replace it... i want the same modal popup to be show on index.html.. as it get hide beside the iframe border/area... Hope you are getting